# How can I embed youtube videos so they play on my HTC Wildfire?

Tags: htc-wildfire, youtube

I have created a youtube video and embedded in on this page:

http://tanguay.info/test169.htm

I tried to play it on my HTC Wildfire in the default browser, but it says there is no flash player installed.

However, I know I have played youtube videos before on this device, so it must be possible.

**What do I have to change so that my HTC Wildfire can play embedded youtube vidoes that I produce?**

Comment: The Wildfire only supports Flash Lite, so I don't know that you can do this.

Comment: If you click a link to that video, does the YouTube app launch?

Answer (score 1):

You can produce videos in the [vp8](http://www.webmproject.org/tools/vp8-sdk/) format.  This is Google's answer to HTML5 video and is supported by most of their phones.

You have the option of embedding the video using HTML5 and `<video>` tags, or uploading the mobile friendly version to YouTube and embedding the link in an iFrame like [previously suggested](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/15359/9511).

vp8 is much like H.264 in that they both boast high-quality/low-overhead and both have hardware decoders. WebM is the container format for vp8 and will remain Royalty Free as long as the technology exists, whereas H.264 will require encoders (and possibly decoders) to pay fees for its use.

Answer (score 0):

This question/answer is probably a little "off topic" for this site as it is more of a web development question.

When you embed the youtube video on the page, you have to use the iframe version, as it supports both the "flash" version and the html5 version of the embeded video. The "default" style only supports flash enabled devices, where the iframe style will support both html5 and flash (if needed).

To embed the iframe style you would do this:

`<iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Comment: yes, that is the tag that I used: `<iframe style="border:1px solid #ccc" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/g6ujJB0UYso?rel=0&hd=1&wmode=transparent&showinfo=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` but the HTC wildfire default browser still requires the flash player